React Hydration Error when rendering image

Warning: React does not recognize the fetchPriority prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase fetchpriority instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.**

If you're using next/image package, you can use priority props

im already using it but its so weird that i get this error message

To be honest, if you're already using priority props, then you don't have to use fetchPriority props anymore. Can i see your image code ?







when i comment my navbar components where that codes belong it doesnt show the error

I don't see any fetchPriority in your Image component. There must be something wrong somewhere i think
